# Submit button cannot trigger to run form action

Tags: html, asp.net, forms

I have a problem about submitting the information of a form to its action part.

What I just want to do is that I send contact's information to the hotmail mail address but I couldn't do that.

I couldn't enter **Contact** method in **HomeController** in the no way.

I have to use a **button** to submit the form.

How can I fix the issue?

Here is my **contact.cshtml** class shown below.

```
<form action="/Home/Contact/" method="post" role="form" class="php-email-form">
    
         @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    
         <div class="row">
    
             <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                 <input type="text" name="nameSurname" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Name" required>
             </div>
    
             <div class="col-md-6 form-group mt-3 mt-md-0">
                 <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" required>
             </div>
        </div>
    
        <div class="form-group mt-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Subject" required>
        </div>
    
        <div class="form-group mt-3">
            <textarea class="form-control" name="message" rows="5" placeholder="Message" required></textarea>
        </div>
    
        <div class="my-3"></div>
    
        <div class="text-center">
             <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
    
</form>
```

Here is my **HomeController.cshtml** class shown below.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Contact(string nameSurname = null, string email = null, string subject = null, string message = null)
        {

            if (nameSurname != null && email != null) 
            {
                WebMail.SmtpServer = "smtp.live.com";
                WebMail.EnableSsl = true;
                WebMail.UserName = "Hotmail address";
                WebMail.Password = "password";
                WebMail.SmtpPort = 587;
                WebMail.Send("Hotmail address", subject, email + "-" + message);
                ViewBag.Warning = "Successfull";

            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.Warning = "Error";
            }
            return View();
}
```

Comment: Did you try it with BeginForm html helper? `@using (Html.BeginForm("Contact", "Home", FormMethod.Post)) { ... } `

Comment: @Arsen I wrote this `@using (Html.BeginForm("Contact", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "php-email-form" })) ` but it didn't work.

Comment: With the BeginForm you need to create ViewModel class with the form fields. Then use it in the View by defining the model `@Model ContactInfo`, for example for the "nameSurname" input use this:  `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.NameSurname)`

Comment: @Arsen I fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue after I deleted contact.cshtml and recreate that file again but I still have no idea why it doesn't trigger to submit the process.